# jQuery waypoints infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

Good time of the day!

I am experiencing some trouble with the infinite scroll shortcut (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/) for jQuery waypoints... I have a simple page with this in the body:

```
<div class="user_home">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="heading">...</div>
    <div class="heading">...</div>
    <div class="heading">...</div>
</div>
<a href="src1.html" class="view_more">see more</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view_more').waypoint('infinite', {
            container: '.user_home',
            items: '.heading',
            more: '.view_more',
            offset: 'bottom-in-view'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Page src1.html has 4-5 divs of the same class (heading) and holds a link of class view_more to page src2.html which, in turn, has more divs with class heading but no link in the end.

Everything seems to be correct but it is not working... Can you, please, help?

Comment: I think the plugin should be attached to the container element and not the link. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it still does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not descriptive of the error. Can you give us more information or a link to the not-working site to investigate?